# How to start multiple webdriver instances in Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have to automate multiple webpages using Selenium. The preferred method is - WebDriver with Python on Windows. Since there number of webpages to test is very very large, I am trying to figure out if I can make this process parallel. E.g. From command line, I execute

```
python script1.py
```

Say I have 100 such scripts and I want to execute them in batches of 5 each. Also one requirement is that is 1 out of 5 scripts completes, then the master starts 6th script to always keep 5 scripts in parallel.

I have searched in docs and some forums. But I could not find any help with this. I have done similar thing in the past, but that involved firing multiple browsers actually from code, so kind of different. This involves Python and Webdriver.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something similar where I wanted to run multiple testcases at once. I guess this can be achieved by using [Selenium Grid](http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/) .

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this was downvoted? Anyways, I found a way to do this.

It can be done by importing subprocess module and then passing arguments to the call function as -

```
  subprocess.call(["python", "d:/pysel/hello.py"])
  subprocess.call(["python", "d:/pysel/goodbye.py"])
```

It is not exactly parallel. But may work for my situation.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how I can achieve this using Java.